# React-Native webview window.postMessage just working debug mode on Android

Tags: android, react-native, webview

I have injected this js to webview. :

```
var msgP = document.createElement('p');
msgP.setAttribute('id', 'msgLabel');
msgP.setAttribute('style', 'color:red');
msgP.innerHTML = '{0}';    
msgP.onclick = function() {window.postMessage('some Data'); }
document.querySelector('#login-form').appendChild(msgP);
```

The above code works just when the debug mode is enabled!

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved just by adding this line to the first of my js:

```
tmpWin = window;
```

I don't know why and how this fix the problem.